# problem after uploading file to web host

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a .xml file in my App_Data folder, I can access it fine in my localhost, however after uploading it to my webhost I got the following:

> ASP.NET is not authorized to access
>   the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource
>   to the ASP.NET request identity.
>   ASP.NET has a base process identity
>   (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5
>   or Network Service on IIS 6) that is
>   used if the application is not
>   impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity
>   will be the anonymous user (typically
>   IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file,
>   right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the
>   Security tab. Click "Add" to add the
>   appropriate user or group. Highlight
>   the ASP.NET account, and check the
>   boxes for the desired access.

So who should I grant access to read? There's 3 user in my web host and all seems to have read access set to them.. one is NETWORK_SERVICE, IUSR_MACHINENAME and my user. So what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See following
http://www.afterlogic.com/kb/articles/how-to-assign-correct-permissions-to-appdata-folder-of-webmail-pro-aspnet

Comment: problem is that I don't have an Internet Guest Account user